# Angular2 NgModel not allowed as constructor parameter

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I'm trying out the code in [this Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/OZsBykh76cbmkE4UdEeQ/) using the latest Angular2 build.

For rating.component.ts, my Typescript editor (Visual Studio 2015) is not accepting NgModel as a parameter type in the constructor. Is there another way to assign "this" to the valueAccessor property of ngModel?

```
constructor(@Self() public cd:NgModel) {
    cd.valueAccessor = this;
}
```

Comment: What does "is not accepting NgModel as a parameter type in the constructor." mean exactly? This is perfectly valid. Without the exact error message it's impossible to know what's going on.

Comment: @angular/common has no exported member 'NgModel'. Where can I export NgModel from?

Comment: `@angular/forms`. Also ensure you have `imports: [BrowserModule /* or CommonModule*/, FormsModule]` in your `@NgModule(...)`

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm seeing that ValueAccessor does not exist on type typeof NgModel.

Comment: Doesn't look like it has a `valueAccessor` property https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html. Seems you are trying to implement outdated examples.

Comment: I am aware that this is an old example. My question is how to do the same thing using the latest Angular2 build.

Comment: I don't know, but I'm sure there are newer examples out there.

Comment: My bad. Not sure why it is not in the docs. But "cd.valueAccessor = ..." worked. I had a typo with a capital V.